# C# equivalent of rjust in python

Tags: c#, python

I am using rjust in python to format a table how would this be done in C#?

```
print 'Interpret: +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+'
print 'Interpret: |   0 ' + 'Example'.rjust(14) + '|'.rjust(9)
print 'Interpret: +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+'
```

It should output something like:

```
Interpret: +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
Interpret: |   0        Example        |
Interpret: +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Interpret: |   0 " + "Example".PadLeft(14) + "|".PadLeft(9);   
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: could you  explain  why ? both have the same  behavior

Answer (score 0):

I would use string formatting.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Interpret: |   0 {"Example",14} {'|',9}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try using x.PadLeft(9+x.Length), where x is your string.